# HTML variable image width with fixed height

Tags: php, html, css, image, size

Im hitting a road block here. I have a dynamic site, where the user uploads images, and it displays it on the page. Thats all fine and dandy, but im sure we have all ran into the scenario where images of a non defined size can really mess up our graphical presentation by overflowing and pushing other elements. So, im wondering if there is a a way where you can set a defined size for an image (in my case height) and have the width just scale to retain proportions. Ive tried just setting the height attribute  and no width, but that didnt display anything (like the width was set to 0). Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: resize the actual image with php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php) to resize the image:

```
<?php

$thumb = new Imagick();
$thumb->readImage('myimage.gif');    
$thumb->resizeImage(320,240,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
$thumb->writeImage('mythumb.gif');
$thumb->clear();
$thumb->destroy(); 

?>
```

Edit: to maintain the aspect ratio use [scaleImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.scaleimage.php), set the value for the dimension you want to resize and 0 to the other dimension to maintain aspect ratio:

```
$im->scaleImage(0, 300);
```

Comment: Does this work to resize and maintain aspect ratio? I dont want ot use a fixed size as some images are like 200x200 and others are 150x200 for instance.

Comment: I edited my answer, you can use scaleImage if you want to resize only one dimension and the other to be resized according to the original aspect ratio